# Unity:can not see anything after sceneLoaded

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, load, scene

When I load a Scene,I conclude it's time-consuming.

```
Debug.LogError($" load  {Time.time}");
SceneManager.LoadScene("GameScene");   

private static void CallBack(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode sceneType)
{
    Debug.LogError($" scene   {SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name}    time  {Time.time}");
}
```

From Debug,I know it cost roughly 0.03s.But if direct observation,all the Gameobject in Scene will apear after about 1s. wonder what caused this and how to solve?

Comment: Try make it `Debug.Log` or `Debug.LogWarning` .. not sure but in general I think an `LogError` often causes the code after it not being executed. Did you try using [`SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.html) instead?

Comment: I use LogError because of It's color,red always stands out better than white.But it dosen't have any effect on the code,right?My project is small,so i don't want to use SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync and add a progress bar.I think maybe LoadScene is enough.But I'm not sure due to my poor experience.

Comment: You know that you can also only make the color red by using e.g. `Debug.Log("<font color=red>Your Red Text Here!</font>");` .. thing is that throwing an error might lead to misbehaviour

Comment: oh,cool.I learn it.But I still can't understand why that Gameobjects will not apear soonr when loadscene callback.I debg in Gameobjects's Start and I find it's at the same time as the callback.I don't know why can't find them even though after their Start.

Comment: Can you see them in the Hierarchy?

Comment: The appeal happened on Android phones.In the Editor,Gameobjects will apear soon,so I can't figure out what what happened.